# Weird distancing Java 3d

Tags: java, math, 3d, java-3d

I will show some images about my problems, so everything will be easier to understand:

[Image 1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/152/stackover.jpg/)
[Image 2](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/stackn.jpg/)

My first image shows the axis (x- axis made of cylinders, y-axis made of cones and z-axis made of spheres) and 3 cylinders positioned as follows:

Cylinder above x-axis (right) supports RotZ(PI/4) and RotX(0). Cylinder above the z-axis(left) supports RotX(PI/4) and RotZ(0). Cylinder in the middle supports RotX(PI/4) and RotZ(PI/4).

My second image shows 3 cylinders at exactly the same angle values, but with a sphere at their origin and changed perspective, to make obvious what is weird: that the upper cylinder(experimentally the "x-axis" cylinder) is closer to the middle cylinder (middle cylinder in the  first image) than the lower cylinder ("z-axis) cylinder in the first image). The difference can be seen from **any** perspective, so not the perspective is the problem.

I have considered that the problem might be the way I am making the rotations. Cylinders have 2f length, so I translate the cylinder to (0,1,0) first, so that the point in the middle of the circle at one end of the cylinder. The idea is that I want to rotate around the (0,0,0) point. Then make the rotations.
Could this be the problem?

The code below shows how cylinders are placed

```
 private void addSimpleBound(float x,float y,float z)
    {


    Cylinder b=new Cylinder();
    TransformGroup tg=new TransformGroup();
    tg.addChild(b);
    TransformGroup element=translate(tg, new Vector3f(0f,1f,0f)); 
    TransformGroup gr=rotate(element,xAngle,zAngle);
    elements.addChild(gr);
}
    TransformGroup rotate(Node node,
        double xAngle,
        double zAngle)
{

    Transform3D tiltAxisXform = new Transform3D();
    Transform3D tempTiltAxisXform = new Transform3D();
    tiltAxisXform.rotX(xAngle);
    tempTiltAxisXform.rotZ(zAngle);
    tiltAxisXform.mul(tempTiltAxisXform);
    TransformGroup rotatedGroup = new TransformGroup(tiltAxisXform);
    rotatedGroup.addChild(node);
    return rotatedGroup;
}// The rotation method
```

[image: Perspective view with the axes]

Comment: Can you show how exactly you create the cylinder and translate and rotate everything?

Comment: Cylinder is first at (0,0,0) in a vertical position. I translate it to (0,1,0), in the same position, so the "bottom" circle of the cylinder is with its center at (0,0,0). Then rotX first and then rotZ.
The angles of rotation are given by the user.
If you still think it is needed, I can add printscreens, but I hope I clarifyed

Comment: I'd wager the order between rotation and translation needs to be inversed, but can you provide some source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Per comments, the end points of your cylinders are at

```
  (sqrt(0.5), sqrt(0.5), 0),
  (0, sqrt(0.5), sqrt(0.5)),
  (sqrt(0.5), 0.5, 0.5)
```

which means that the distances actually are unsymmetric. For a more symmetric result, the second rotation would have to be around the y axis.

**Original answer:**

This is not weird at all. The ends of your cylinders are at

```
  (sqrt(0.5), sqrt(0.5), 0),
  (0, sqrt(0.5), sqrt(0.5)),
  (0.5, sqrt(0.5), 0.5)
```

The distance from the first end to the second is 1, the distance from the first to the third (or from the second to the third) is sqrt(1 - sqrt(0.5)) < 1.

P.S. if you want to make the image more symmetrical, you could put the end of the third cylinder to (sqrt(0.5),0,sqrt(0.5)).

Comment: But It's not about the distance between the first to the second. It's first to third and second to third that should be equal

Comment: I see. Is the top of the third cylinder really at (0.5, sqrt(0.5), 0.5)?

Comment: Wait, no, it isn't actually. As said in the other post you answered (thanks again) the formula of the point is (sin alpha, cos alpha*cos beta, cos alpha*sin beta) that means (sqrt(0.5),0.5,0.5)) actually. Just realised

But if so, it's even worse, because it would have been legit to have the x and z values at the same value. But by the determined formula, doesn't quite work that way.

Comment: I see. (0.5, sqrt(0.5), 0.5) is when your second rotation is around the y axis. Seems like more than one rotation at a time is already confusing me.

Comment: Belive me, friend, my had has been spinning all the week to figure out that. Thanks to you, part of it is done

Comment: Well, actually there is no error. The C point is at (sqrt(0.5),0.5,0.5)) so it is obvious that x and z are not equal. I also managed to get a geometrical explanation